# Autocorrelation of $\frac{1}{9}(\omega_{t-1}+\omega_{t}+\omega_{t+1})$

Tags: time-series

Find the autocorrelation function of $v_t=\frac{1}{9}(\omega_{t-1}+\omega_{t}+\omega_{t+1})$

What I have tried:

$$\rho(h) = \frac{\gamma(t+h, t)}{\sqrt{\gamma(t+h, t+h)\gamma(t,t)}}=\frac{\gamma(h)}{\gamma(0)}$$

I have actually got this for $h=0$, however, I am struggling with $h=1$, for example:

$$\rho(1) = \frac{\gamma(t+1,t)}{\sqrt{\gamma(t+1, t+1)\gamma(t,t)}}$$

Therefore,

$$\gamma(t+1,t) = \frac{1}{9}cov([\omega_t+\omega_{t+1}+\omega_{t+2}],[\omega_{t-1}+\omega_{t}+\omega_{t+1}])$$

I am unsure with simplifying this.

Comment: what is $\omega_t$?

Comment: @Exodd The white noise series

Comment: If it is supposed gaussian centered and independant we can get interesting results.